Star Alliance Gold Privileges: companion needs to be on same PNR?
Star Alliance gold comes with several privileges e.g. the lounge, priority check in, extra baggage, etc.
I know some of these extend to a companion? E.g. lounge access.
But is there a list of which privileges are for the SA Gold member alone and which ones extend to the companion? E.g. the Fast Track security, or priority boarding etc.
Furthermore, for the "companion" what are the rules. Eg in the past for lounge access any companion with a SA flight counted, then they made it only for passengers on the same flight as the Gold member?
Are there certain privileges which will only come by being on a common PNR?
If it matters my status is Elite on the Turkish Miles and Smiles program ( in case different airlines handle this differently)

Same flight is generally required, not same PNR. I did this myself once - brought a guest into a lounge with SA gold, same flight different booking.

The official Star Alliance lounge policy is straightforward: your companion has to be on the same flight.

You are entitled to bring one guest travelling on [...] the same Star Alliance flight departing from the local airport.

Airlines can be more lenient if they want to, and so can the individual "lounge dragons" who grant access, but that's the letter of the law.
Priority checkin and boarding for companions on the same flight is also universal as far as I can tell, although I'm not sure if there's a policy for this.
Fast Track/Gold Track, however, seems to vary by airport.  In my experience manual checkers don't give a crap and will happily wave your companion through, but this doesn't work with automated gates where you need to scan your boarding pass.
